# JPA table primary key being incremented by 2 instead of 1

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I don't understand why the primary key of my *usr* table always increments by two instead of one when inserting a new user in my application. I am using the Oracle11g database. If I manually insert into the *usr* table everything is working fine.

Also, the *usr* table and the *role* table have a *usr_role* join table togeher with a composed primary key. JPA inserts the right primary key for *usr* into the join table. Only in the *usr* table it's incremented by two.

The SQL I use to create the user schema:

```
CREATE TABLE usr (
id NUMBER(19) PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL CHECK(LENGTH(password) >= 6),
username VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON usr TO forum_user;

DROP SEQUENCE seq_usr;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_usr;
GRANT ALL ON seq_usr TO forum_user;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_usr
BEFORE INSERT ON usr
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN :NEW.id := seq_usr.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

The user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "FORUM", name = "USR")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "USR_ID_GENERATOR",
            sequenceName = "SEQ_USR",
            schema = "FORUM",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "USR_ID_GENERATOR"
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 40)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+", message = "has to be valid")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6, max = 10)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 20)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USR_ROLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public boolean addRole(Role role) {
        if (roles == null) {
            roles = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return roles.add(role);
    }
}
```

This is the JPA SQL output:

```
19:50:16,289 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_2_, role0_.name as name2_2_ from FORUM.ROLE role0_ where role0_.name=?
19:50:16,291 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) Hibernate: select FORUM.SEQ_USR.nextval from dual
19:50:16,292 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) Hibernate: insert into FORUM.USR (email, password, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
19:50:16,293 INFO  [stdout] (default task-12) Hibernate: insert into USR_ROLE (USR_ID, ROLE_ID) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: why don't you use sequence 
`CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USR
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 1000
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;`
instead of using trigger?
I believe trigger will only execute once there is a data updated, causing update it once there is an update.

Comment: Thanks a lot @fg78nc, I am creating the sequence like that now and the error is gone. Perhaps you want to create an answer so I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Florian :) , I have posted answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use sequence as follows :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_USR 
    MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 1000 
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

instead of using trigger. I believe trigger will only execute once there is a data update, causing another update once there is an update already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the database and ask for nextval there to isolate if the problem is in Oracle or some crazy thing in JPA configuration.

Comment: If I call **SELECT seq_user.nextval from dual** it is incrementing correctly by one each time.